# Naming convention for internationalized (i18n) database fields

Tags: database, internationalization, naming-conventions, naming

What is the 'best practice' naming convention for internationalized database fields? In the current code base, the convention is to use the '_id' suffix for foreign key fields. But if a field is internationalized, should we append an '_i18n' suffix to the field? EG: 'label_i18n' as opposed to 'label'? Pros and cons?

Comment: Smells like Hungarian, albeit Sys.

Comment: Who said it was a fairly standard convention to use the '_id' suffix? Also, what exactly do you mean by "internationalized fields" are you talking about Unicode?

Comment: Internationalized fields as in it contains a mapping of locale=>localized value pairs.

Comment: also, get rid of those underscores!! ;)

Comment: I like `*Id` -- not for a *key*, but for something that represent an *id*, which may be a key..

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing i18n, then you should have a separate table storing the fields.

E.g.

```
Table Fields (blogpost):
- id, INT (10)
- user_id, INT(10)

i18n table (blogpost_i18n):
- blogpost_id, INT(10)
- title, VARCHAR(255)
- content, TEXT
- lang, VARCHAR(10)
```

where the lang column stores the i18n code for that language, this way you can add as many languages as you want.